# Custom chains Iptables and predefined

Tags: linux, networking, iptables, linux-networking

Hi I wonder how do custom chains work in iptables.

I have found interesting rules for custom chains.

```
iptables -t nat -N CUSTOMCHAIN
iptables -t nat -A CUSTOMCHAIN -d 127.0.0.0/8 -j RETURN
iptables -t nat -A CUSTOMCHAIN -p tcp -j REDIRECT --to-ports 80
```

There are  a lot questions about these rules

1. In the first rule we are creating a custom chain in the `nat table`, but in which one ? There multiple nat tables, which one is used ?
2. If packet got inside CUSTOMCHAIN but destination address is localhost, then just return it to the normal flow, am I right ?
3. All tcp other tcp packets should be redirected to the port 80. But how do packets get inside our CUSTOMCHAIN, and when do they get redirected to our custom chain ?

Could someone please explain these rules and answer my questions
I would be grateful for any help. 
Thanks

[image: Iptables flow]

Answer (score 1):

1. There are no multiple nat tables, but multiple chains ..and you just created new one.
2. Yes
3. When you set a "jump" action from a (default chains) rule

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but about the 3 question. Could you please explain this in more details, how do packets get into my custom chain ?

Comment: # (sample) in nat/prerouting, if packet enter from interface eth1 >> jump to my custom chain (CUSTOMCHAIN)

iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING --in-interface eth1 --jump CUSTOMCHAIN