# bridge isn't forwarding non local traffic

Tags: iptables, routing, virtual-machines, vlan, forwarding

I'm experiencing the following issue, i have two virtual machines connected and vlan tagged traffic is passed lets say from A to B.

The traffic passed from A to B is tagged and I need to strip the tag on the incoming traffic, add a new tag and re transmit it on the same interface it was received from.

I'm working on machine B a pure linux host, my plan is to configure 2 vlan interfaces without configured ip on the same ethernet interface(vmxnet3) port and use ebtables in order to forward the frames from one vlan interface to the other.

**I can see the traffic with tcpdump (!) but the vlan interface RX counters are still !?.**

Any idea what I am missing ?

**I didn't configure any ip addresses to the vlan interfaces and didn't add any route.**

Update :

I configured a bridge of the two vlan interfaces :

```
brctl show br0
bridge name     bridge id               STP enabled     interfaces
br0             8000.005056ad3e37       yes             ens192.111
                                                        ens192.222


ens192.111: flags=4419<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,PROMISC,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        inet6 fe80::250:56ff:fead:3e37  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x20<link>
        ether aa:5a:5a:ad:ae:a7  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 0  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 840  bytes 44488 (43.4 KiB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

ens192.222: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        inet6 fe80::250:56ff:fead:3e37  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x20<link>
        ether a0:a0:a6:ad:ae:a7  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 480768  bytes 366765149 (349.7 MiB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 839  bytes 44462 (43.4 KiB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0
```

I have the following rules, I can see the messages in the log but for some reason traffic isn't passed on ens192.111. any idea what to do next ?

```
ebtables -P FORWARD  ACCEPT
ebtables -A FORWARD --log-level info --log-ip --log-prefix EBFW_FORWARD

Mar 18 09:11:59 LIN-VAR29 kernel: EBFW_FORWARD IN=ens192.222 OUT=ens192.111 MAC source = aa:bb:aa:fe:00:22 MAC dest = ca:ca:cb:1e:88:0f proto = 0x0800 IP SRC=182.180.182.52 IP DST=152.114.179.211 IP tos=0x00, IP proto=6 SPT=37415 DPT=80
```

Thanks

Comment: If the traffic's destination is not your Linux box, it will pass through the `FORWARD` chain, not `INPUT`. Cf. [picture under this question](https://serverfault.com/q/859953/530633)

Comment: Hi @PiotrP.Karwasz, Thanks for the fast reply, I cant see the frames in FORWARD chain as well. I don't  think that the incoming frames are forwarded. no ip is configured to the vlan interface and no routing as well.. but I do wanna catch those frames and forward them.. any idea how might be able to do it ?

Comment: I missed the _"no IP address"_ part. Since the frames' destination is not your interface MAC address, iptables won't see it, [ebtables](https://ebtables.netfilter.org/examples/basic.html) might. What you want to do is to [bridge](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Network_bridge) the two [VLAN interfaces](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/VLAN).

Comment: Hi, @PiotrP.Karwasz, Thanks again ! now when i'm doing tcpdump on the bridge I can see the frames. I can see the frames in the log after configuring rules in ebtables. i'll continue and i'll update here when done

Comment: Hi @PiotrP.Karwasz, according to ebtables logs traffic is passed to the other device but nothing happens any idea what to do next ? I update the original question with more data. Thanks A lot !!!

Comment: According to your logs frames are forwarded between interfaces, as you asked. Whether some host reads it or not depends whether the destination MAC `ca:ca:cb:1e:88:0f` is on the `222` VLAN or not. You can see what the bridge learned so far about the `MAC`s of your network with `bridge fdb show`.

Comment: only if the dest mac is of ens192.111 it will accept the frame ? If i want it to accept everything what should i do ?

Comment: Check [this answer](https://serverfault.com/a/879038/530633).